# Error en método main , incompatible type error

Tags: java

Estoy creando un programa que cuando se imprima un
autor, se debe de mostrar toda la información de todos los libros que éste
ha escrito. Añadir un atributo nuevo en la clase Autor que será “librosEscritos: Lista(Libro)”.

He ampliado el programa para que almacene también los autores creados (los libros los almacenará cada autor creado), de manera que se puede dotar al programa la posibilidad de listar todos los libros de autores que tengan un género (sexo) determinado y que no valgan más de un determinado precio.

No puedo utilizar ArrayList.

[image: Error metodo main]

Este es el código de las dos clases:

```
public class Libro {

    private final String nombreLibro;
    private final double precioLibro;
    private final int cantidadEnStock;
    private final  Autor[] autores;
    private final String librosEscritos;

    public Libro(String nombreLibro, double precioLibro, int cantidadEnStock, Autor[] autores, String librosEscritos) {
        this.nombreLibro = nombreLibro;
        this.precioLibro = precioLibro;
        this.cantidadEnStock = cantidadEnStock;
        this.autores = autores;
        this.librosEscritos = librosEscritos;
    }

    //Metodos get y set
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombreLibro;
    }

    public String getNombreLibro() {
        return nombreLibro;
    }

    public double getPrecioLibro() {
        return precioLibro;
    }

    public int getCantidadEnStock() {
        return cantidadEnStock;
    }

    public Autor[] getAutores() {
        return autores;
    }

    public String getLibrosEscritos() {
        return librosEscritos;
    }

    public String setLibrosEscritos() {
        return librosEscritos;
    }

    public Autor[] setAutores() {
        return autores;
    }

    public String setNombre() {
        return nombreLibro;
    }

    public double setPrecioLibro() {
        return precioLibro;
    }

    public int setCantidadEnStock() {
        return cantidadEnStock;
    }
```

---

```
public class Autor {

    private final String[] listaNombreAutor;
    private final String email;
    private final char[] listaSexoAutores;
    private final Libro[] libros;
    private final Libro[] listaLibrosEscritos;

    public Autor(String[] listaNombreAutor, String email, char[] listaSexoAutores, Libro[] libros, Libro[] listaLibrosEscritos) {
        this.listaNombreAutor = listaNombreAutor;
        this.email = email;
        this.listaSexoAutores = listaSexoAutores;
        this.libros = libros;
        this.listaLibrosEscritos = listaLibrosEscritos;
    }   

    //Metodos get y set
    public String[] getListaNombreAutor() {
        return listaNombreAutor;
    }

    public Libro[] getListaLibrosEscritos() {
        return listaLibrosEscritos;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }    

    public Libro[] getLibros() {
        return libros;
    }

    public char[] getListaSexoAutores() {
        return listaSexoAutores;
    }

     public char[] setListaSexoAutores() {
        return listaSexoAutores;
    }        

    public String[] setListaNombreAutor() {
        return listaNombreAutor;
    }

    public Libro[] setLibros() {
        return libros;
    }

    public String setEmail() {
        return email;
    }
```

Comment: Te marca ese error debido a que en tu contructor estas recibiendo un arreglo de autores `public Libro(String nombreLibro, double precioLibro, int cantidadEnStock, Autor[] autores, String librosEscritos)` y tu le estas enviando un `string`

Comment: Deberas crear un arreglo de autores para cada instancia de tu clase libro

Comment: Tienes dependencia circular entre tus clases en los constructores. No será posible crear instancias de esas clases a menos que asignes `null`. Te recomiendo cambiar el diseño de tus clases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el asunto de la referencia circular, eso se puede solucionar con la ayuda de `getters` y `setters` que se aseguran que existe una relación bilateral entre los objetos. Un ejemplo en código:

```
package classes;

public class Libro {

    private Autor autor;

    public Autor getAutor() {
        return autor;
    }

    public void setAutor(Autor autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
    }



}
```

La clase simplificado de `Libro` tiene un setter para el `Autor`

```
package classes;

public class Autor {

    private Libro[] libros;

    public Autor(Libro[] libros){
        setLibros(libros);
    }

    private void setLibros(Libro[] libros){
        for (Libro libro : libros){
            libro.setAutor(this);
        }
        this.libros=libros;
    }

    public Libro[] getLibros(){
            return libros;
    }

    public void addLibro(Libro libro){
        Libro[] libros = new Libro[this.libros.length+1];
        // copiar libros
        for (int i = 0 ; i < this.libros.length; i++) { libros[i] = this.libros[i]; };
        // agregar libro
        libro.setAutor(this);
        libros[libros.length-1]=libro;
        // asignar
        this.libros=libros;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Autor a = new Autor(new Libro[]{new Libro(), new Libro(), new Libro()});
        for (Libro libro : a.getLibros()){
            System.out.println(String.format("Libro %s Autor %s",
                    libro.toString(),libro.getAutor().toString()));
        }
    }

}
```

Como se vé, la clase `Autor` puede usar el método `setLibros(...)` en su constructor, y dentro de este método (tal cual que en `addLibro(...)`) se asegura que el autor del Libro esta actualizado.

Comment: muchas gracias, me refería a esto. Me has resuelto la duda

Answer (score 2):

El error se debe a que estás usando un constructor con el siguiente prototipo

```
Libro(String, int, int, String, String)
```

Dicho constructor no existe, y es por eso que el IDE te muestra un error de compilación.

Tu único constructor utiliza el prototipo

```
Libro(String, double, int, Autor[], String)
```

Cabe mencionar que nunca podras crear una instancia de `Libro` y `Autor` puesto que tienes un circulo en las dependencias

- Para crear un libro necesitas una lista de autores
- Para crear un autor necesitas una lista de libros

Y he ahí el bucle, se puede corregir mandando `null`'s pero no es lo correcto.

Hay varios errores semánticos en ambas clases que me es imposible determinar el funcionamiento de tu programa, por lo tanto no puedo refactorizar el código y dar una respuesta con la solución.

No obstante para no dejarte en blanco te diré los errores:

1. La clase `Autor` solo debe conocerse a sí mismo, él no necesita saber nada acerca de la clase `Libro`.
2. La clase `Autor` y `Libro` no deben funcionar como almacenes de metadatos.
   Por ejemplo, si quieres guardar y recuperar los libros que ha escrito cierto 
   autor, debes crear una clase `X` que se encargue de ello, imagina que tengo una clase `Stock` que su fin es devolver la cantidad de libros disponibles. 
   la clase `Libro` tiene un método llamado getCantidadEnStock() dicho método son accesos inmediatos de la clase `Stock`.

Ejemplo:

```
public class Stock
{
    private static Libro[] libros;
    private static int[] enStock;

    private Stock()
    {
        // impide crear instancias de la clase Stock
    }

    public static void agregar(Libro libro, int ctdStock)
    {
        libros[SIZE] = libro;
        enStock[SIZE]= ctdStock;
        SIZE++;
    }


    public static int getCtdStock(Libro libro){
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_LIBROS; i++){
            if(libros[i].equals(libro))
                return enStock[i];
        }
        return 0;
    }


    static 
    {
        libros = new Libros[MAX_LIBROS];
        enStock = new int[MAX_LIBROS];
    }

    private static int MAX_LIBROS = 10;
    private static int SIZE = 0;
}
```

El archivo `Libro.java`

```
public class Libro
{
    ...
    public int getCantidadEnStock(){
        return Stock.getCtdStock(this);
    }
}
```

El método main

```
Libro libro1 = new Libro(...);
Stock.agregar(libro1, 20); // agrega el libro1 y establece 20 unidades en stock
System.out.println(libro1.getCantidadEnStock()); // imprime 20
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar mi pregunta, el ejemplo me ha despejado las dudas que tenia.